# bootstrap 4 toggle appear to work in the markup but not in layout

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, sass

I have bootstrap 4 navbar component highly customed ,when I click navbar-toggle button at small screen it's not working however , in console it shows markup changes as if it's working , I tried to increase z-index , check display , check visibility but no thing works .

here is a link to the page : https://aboshalby2017.000webhostapp.com/

here is the html code :

```
<head>
<!--important meta-->
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>Mahmoud M.</title>
<!--css files-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontawesome-all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<!--site icon-->
<link rel="icon" href="images/icon.ico">
<!--google fonts-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<!--start navbar-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md p-0 flex-wrap align-items-start">
    <!--the brand name-->
    <div class="navbar-brand text-center bg-white m-0 w-100">
        <h2 class="text-capitalize">mahmoud m.</h2>
        <span class="float-right">web designer</span>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <!--toggler button-->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </button>
    <!--togglable content-->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-0 row no-gutters list-unstyled w-100 h-100 align-items-center">
            <li data-class=".home" class="w-100 nav-item col-xl-12 col-auto text-right active">home</li>
            <li data-class=".works" class="w-100 nav-item col-xl-12 col-auto text-right">works</li>
            <li data-class=".about" class="w-100 nav-item col-xl-12 col-auto text-right">about</li>
            <li data-class=".services" class="w-100 nav-item col-xl-12 col-auto text-right">services</li>
            <li data-class=".contact" class="w-100 nav-item col-xl-12 col-auto text-right">contact</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--the footer of sidebar-->
    <footer class="text-center d-none d-xl-block">
        <div class="copyright text-center">
            <p class="text-capitalize">
                all copyright reserved <br> &copy; 2018 <br>
                <span>mahmoud mostafa</span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="social">
            <ul class="list-unstyled text-center">
                <li class="d-inline-block"><a href="https://www.upwork.com/o/profiles/users/_~01f0908562a25e2c90/" target="_blank" class="d-block"><img class="upwork-green d-block w-100 h-100 rounded-circle" src="images/upwork-green.png" alt=""></a>
                </li>
                <li class="d-inline-block"><a href="https://github.com/drMahmoudMostafa" target="_blank" class="d-block"><i class="fab fa-github w-100 h-100 d-block"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="d-inline-block"><a href="https://plus.google.com/116765594008435589298" target="_blank" class="d-block"><i class="fab fa-google-plus w-100 h-100 d-block"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="d-inline-block"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/mahmoud-mostafa-b1508a160/" target="_blank" class="d-block"><i class="fab fa-linkedin w-100 h-100 d-block"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </footer>
</nav>
<!--endart navbar-->
<!--js files-->
<!-- 1- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- 2- popper -->
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- 3- bootstrap -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- 4- nicescroll -->
<script src="js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
<!-- 5- main js file -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

here is scss code :

```
    @import "bootstrap/functions";
    @import "bootstrap/variables";
    @import "bootstrap/breakpoints";
    /****************************************************

                    navebar section

****************************************************/

.navbar {
    background: $mainColor1;
    width: 20%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 5px -.0009px 20px #000;
    font-family: "opan-sans", sans-serif;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9000;
    @include media-breakpoint-down(lg) {
        width: 100%;
        bottom: auto;
        right: 0;
        min-height: 40px !important;
        height: 80px !important;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .navbar-brand {
        color: #333;
        padding: 40px 30px;
        font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
        span {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            color: $mainColor4;
        }
        @include media-breakpoint-down(lg) {
            width: 30% !important;
            padding: 10px;
            display: inline-block;
            span {
                margin: 0;
            }
        }
        @include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
            width: 50% !important;
        }
    }

    .navbar-toggler {

        border-color: #fff;
        margin: 14px 22px;
        i {
            color: #fff;
            width: 44px;
            height: 44px;
            font-size: 190%;
            line-height: 30px;
            padding: 5px;
        }
    }

    .navbar-collapse {
        flex-basis: auto;
        @include media-breakpoint-down(lg) {
            display: inline-block;
            float: right;
            width: 70% !important;
            height: 100%;
        }
        @include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
            width: 100% !important;
            float: none;
            height: auto !important;
        }
        ul {
            @include media-breakpoint-down( lg) {
                display: inline-flex;
                margin: 0;
                justify-content: flex-end;
            }
            li {
                background: linear-gradient(#323b3f, #2e3639);
                color: lighten( $mainColor4, 20%);
                padding: 10px 25px;
                cursor: pointer;
                @include transition (.1s);
                &:hover {
                    background: $mainColor2;
                    color: #fff;
                    padding-right: 30px
                }
                @include media-breakpoint-down( lg) {
                    height: 100%;
                    padding: 25px 20px;
                    text-align: center !important;
                    width: auto !important;
                    display: inline-block;
                }
                @include media-breakpoint-down(sm){
                    height: auto;
                    width: 100% !important;
                    display: block;
                }
            }
            .active {
                background: $mainColor2;
                color: #fff;
                padding-right: 30px
            }
        }
    }
    footer {
        font-size: 15px;
        color: $mainColor4;
        margin-top: 100px;
        @include media-breakpoint-down(lg) {
            display: none;
        }
        .copyright {
            span {
                color: $mainColor2;
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

thanks anyway ;

Comment: Please clarify the question and add a **minimal** example to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @ZimSystem I edit the description of the question - hope it's clarified - and edit a link .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have

```
@media (max-width: 1199px)
    .navbar {
                width: 100%;
                bottom: auto;
                right: 0;
                min-height: 40px !important;
                height: 80px !important;
                overflow: hidden; /* remove this */
   }
}
```

remove `overflow:hidden` from `.navbar` and your code will work. It still needs some more customization , for example you have `@media (max-width: 1199px)
.navbar .navbar-collapse { display:inline-block }` . You need to use `display:none` for mobile devices.

SO in conclusion, you need to change the styles for the `navbar` and it's components when on mobile devices.

Comment: thanks man , this works , however not smoothly , and not move main sections - which navbar link to - down and cover it .

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when going from 3 to 4 Bootstrap, the markup existed, but I didn't see the modal. And I found the problem

```
<div class="modal post fade in" id="modalForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;"></div>
```

class has property

```
.fade {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

I changed  opacity from 0 to 1

```
.fade {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

and it works to me